# Showing linearity

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this function linear?

$ \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}, (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$

Well.. Usually I have to show

$L1: F(x+y) = F(x) + F(y)$

$L2: k\cdot F(x) = F(k \cdot x) $ right?

So:
$F(x+y) = F((x_n) + (y_n)) = \lim (x_n + y_n) = \lim x_n + \lim y_n$ 
and $F(k\cdot x) = F(k \cdot (x_n)) = \lim (k \cdot x_n) = k \cdot \lim x_n$

So what I have to do is showing the rules calculating with limits?

Comment: The function is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, only on the points where the sequence converges.

Comment: What is the level of rigor required for your class?  Are we assuming that $(x_n)$ converges?

Comment: Hi! I don't know if we can assume that, there is no information given. @ coffeemath: Sorry, but what does that mean for linearity?